# support center app with twilio or pubnub

Tags: twilio, appcelerator, pubnub

I try to build a support center app with twilio or pubnub. it's fairly simple:

1. user starts a public chat
2. someone from the support team accepts -> public chat turns private
3. when supporter has anwsered the chat request, chat turns public again

The app would be build with titanium appcelerator for the user and angular for the support team.

**Twilio**

Since twilio doesn't provide a native titanium sdk, I looked into its programmable chat rest api - but in my opinion it lacks one important feature: when i open up a channel, I can't modify the `create_by` property. It is `system` by default. All I can do is, get all the channels at once for all users.

So I can't get all the channels one user is subscribed to. I would have to manage all channels by myself. **Is that right so far?**

**PubNub**

PubNub on the other hand I don't get. They encourage you to have not more than two channels per connection. But one user has to be able to open as many tickets as he likes. **So how can i organize it?** Also, their approach to private chats is to have a private chat-name. but then I don't know how I could switch between private and public without loosing the history. **Can I move messages from public to private channel?** One way I could think of is having a unique `uuid` assigned to each conversation thread. That way I could group messages into threads, regardless of the channel. **Would that be a valid approach?**

Comment: Quick question, can you not use the Twilio Chat JS SDK in Titanium?

Comment: I tried, but no. I think only when I use a webview.

Comment: Have you tried to create a Titanium wrapper for the native platform? That might be a better solution than using the REST API for this.

Comment: No, since right now I never had a chance to look into that. And I would have to do it for android and ios... Up until now I never did native development for ios.

Comment: The REST API for Twilio Chat is intended to do work on behalf of the system, whereas the client SDKs are intended for use with user. All I can suggest is that you either include a webview and use the JS SDK or find some way to create a Titanium wrapper for both platforms.

Comment: There is a module, does it work? https://github.com/yagitoshiro/TiTwilio

Comment: This would be only voip. I need chat.

Comment: Just a quick response on "They encourage you to have not more than two channels per connection". Where do you get that information? You can have up to 20K channels per client using Channel Groups. And a private channel is just a definition of who can access the channel. If only one person can access (subscribe to) the channel, then it is private. If two can access it, then it is a 1-1 channel, more than 2 and it is group channel. You use Access Manager to control who can subscribe, publish and such. More complete answer to follow soon.

Comment: And see this excellent explanation on using PubNub to create a Support Center app by our CTO, Stephen Blum: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-PubNub-for-making-a-customer-support-app-which-has-basic-features-like-ClickDesk-and-Pure-Chat

Comment: Use [AngularJS Chat Example](http://angularjs.chat/) for both your Web and Mobile apps by wrapping with  PhoneGap for your Mobile App!  Then you can use our [PubNub 4.0x SDK for JavaScript](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-v4) directly including happiness ❤️   now your development experience is 